# The dimensions of my home screen and app drawer have reduced

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

I had my note 4 sm-n910c running marshmallow rooted by supersu chainfire. Today i hit the pro button on supersu and gave it a restart....eversince i have everything shrunk down to small sizes .even the touchwiz, internet all had crashed and wouldnt work, so i had to switch to touchwiz easyhome and chrome. Finally i understood its the dpi problem and restored it using build.prop method. But the dimensions of my homescreen and app drawer dont touch the bottom of the screen. I cant upload my images here but to be exact.the buttons or the scrolls which represent number of pages used to be 14.5cm diagonally but now they are just 10.5 cm diagonally. Youtube whatsapp everything works on full screen. Even the camera had a 10.5 cm covered and the rest area is a black screen. Also my notification bar and other things are still small but managable.

P.S - i have tried dpi combinations and thats not the reason for this malfunction. Also everything still looks thin and small

Answer (score 0):

Try `su` then `wm density reset` and `wm size reset` from ADB shell.

Please remove *any* lockscreen protection - including swipe - prior to doing this, so that if anything goes wrong you're still past the lockscreen and therefore still has ADB access.